# How to mock location on Android?

Tags: java, android, location, android-fusedlocation, mock-location

I use the code below to set a mock location **without requiring the Location permission**.

However, the code is inconsistent on Android devices with the latest Google Play Services version which utilizes the `FusedLocationProviderClient`. Sometimes it works as intented, sometimes the location keeps jumping back and forth, sometimes it doesn't work at all. I also frequently get crashes with the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provider “gps” already exists`. Basically, it's bad code and I want to get rid of it in my app.

What I'm looking for is a full-proof solution that is able to successfuly fake the device's location (without requiring the Location permission), exactly like this [Fake GPS app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lexa.fakegps). I wish to re-create that app in Java. I haven't found anything online that fully works as of May 2020. I'd appreciate your help on that.

```
void setMockLocation() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.addTestProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, false, false,
            false, false, true, true, true, 0, 5);
    locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, true);

    Location mockLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    mockLocation.setLatitude(-33.852);  // Sydney
    mockLocation.setLongitude(151.211);
    mockLocation.setAltitude(10);
    mockLocation.setAccuracy(5);
    mockLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    mockLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(System.nanoTime());
    locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, mockLocation);
}
```